# c fgets char array

Tags: c, char, fgets

I have a problem with `fgets`. I can't save the String "temp" in the if-statement.

The Code:

```
      1 #include <stdio.h>
      2 #include <string.h>
      3 #include<stdlib.h>
      4 
      5 void moep(char** tmp){
      6         FILE *fp;
      7         fp=fopen("moep", "r");
      8         int line_num = 1;
      9         int find_result = 0;
     10         char* str="jochen";
     11         char temp[512];
     12 
     13 while(fgets(temp, 512, fp) != NULL) {
     14                 if((strstr(temp, str)) != NULL) {
     15                         printf("A match found on line: %d    \n", line_num);
     16                         tmp[find_result]=temp;
     17                         printf("\n%s\n", tmp[find_result]    );
     18                         find_result++;
     19                 }
     20                 line_num++;
     21         }
     22 fclose(fp);
     23 printf("tmp[0]:%s\n",tmp[0]);
     24 tmp[1]="ich funktioniere";
     25 }
     26 
     27 int main(){
     28 
     29         char* tmp[1];
     30         moep(tmp);
     31         printf("%s, %s\n",tmp[0],tmp[1]);
     32         return 0;
     33 }
```

and moep is:

```
unwichtig1
jochen g
unwichtig2
unwichtig3
```

The output:

```
 /A match found on line: 2

jochen g

tmp[0]:unwichtig3

��Ł�, ich funktioniere
```

why can't I save "jochen" in `tmp[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning to tmp[1] is assigning to random memory, as you're array isn't that big.
It will have all sorts of bad side effects - including crashing the program.

You are also reusing the temp[] array - so that will keep getting overwritten, you need to copy the string if you want to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems.  I did not look at `moep()` at all, only `main()`.

You probably did not intended to declare `tmp` as:

```
 char* tmp[1];
```

This declares a pointer, but does not point anywhere.  Accessing the second element in it is not "kosher" because it is declared to be one element.  (But it doesn't matter because the array is not allocated.)

Probably you meant

```
 char  tmp[2];
```

This allocates a space for two characters.

Comment: But I want to save a Array of Strings.
If I write:
<pre>char* tmp[125]<code>
I get a segmentation fault with gcc-4.3, but with 4.4 everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a mess.

`temp` is an array of pointers to char. You assign the pointer to temp to the first, second etc. element of that array. That said, this is always the same value, since `temp` itself doesn't change, and it's contents gets overwritten every iteration of the loop.

Use `strncpy()` to copy from one string to another.